# Setup alias to work immediately when created as root without a restart

Tags: bash, root, alias

I have created a Shell script to install some software which runs as root. As part of this process it sets up an alias to point at a shell script to make it easier to run for the user. It does the by appending the alias to `~/.bashrc` in the user account. This is the code that does this:

```
    # Add alias so entering 'statusmonitor' works from any folder
    if grep -q "alias statusmonitor=" "$USER_HOME/.bashrc"; then
        str="Updating 'statusmonitor' alias in .bashrc file..."
        printf "%b %s" "${INFO}" "${str}"
        # Update existing alias for 'statusmonitor'
        sed -i -e "/^alias diginode=/s|.*|alias statusmonitor='$STATUS_MONITOR_SCRIPT'|" $USER_HOME/.bashrc
        printf "%b%b %s Done!\\n" "${OVER}" "${TICK}" "${str}"
    else
        str="Adding 'statusmonitor' alias to .bashrc file..."
        printf "%b %s" "${INFO}" "${str}"
        # Append alias to .bashrc file
        echo "" >> $USER_HOME/.bashrc
        echo "# Alias for Status Monitor so that entering 'statusmonitor' will run this from any folder" >> $USER_HOME/.bashrc
        echo "alias statusmonitor='$STATUS_MONITOR_SCRIPT'" >> $USER_HOME/.bashrc
        printf "%b%b %s Done!\\n" "${OVER}" "${TICK}" "${str}"
    fi
```

`USER_HOME` is a variable that stores the user's home folder e.g. `/home/ubuntu/`

`STATUS_MONITOR_SCRIPT` is a variable that stores the location of the status monitor Shell script - `~/statusmonitor/statusmonitor.sh`

This code above works as expected. The issue is that I then want to load the alias now so the user does not need to log out and log back of the session. I am currently trying this but it does not work:

```
        # Load new alias immediately
    if [ "$NewInstall" = true ]; then
        str="Load new alias now..."
        printf "%b %s" "${INFO}" "${str}"
        sudo -u $USER_ACCOUNT alias diginode="$STATUS_MONITOR_SCRIPT"
        printf "%b%b %s Done!\\n" "${OVER}" "${TICK}" "${str}"
    fi
```

The `USER_ACCOUNT` stores the current user so that it can be called even though the script is running root.

I want to be able to type in 'statusmonitor' the moment the install script finished but it currently does not work until I restart the terminal session. When it runs as root it is staying that the alias command does not exist, even though I am using `sudo -u` to when QAS the user.

Strangely, if when the script has just finished, if I type in the command manually it sets up the alias fine:

```
alias diginode=/home/ubuntu/statusmonitor
```

I am assuming this is a problem of running as root versus as the user. Can anyone help me load the alias without the restart, from within the script running as root?

Comment: I've not done any shell scripts so forgive me if this doesn't help ... but running ```. .bashrc``` from the command line will force the shell to read your .bashrc file and thus load the newly created aliases. I don't know if it would work, but adding ```echo ". .bashrc"``` to your script might work?

Comment: IMHO you're going about this in a very non-*NIX way; root shouldn't be messing with user's files, 3rd party software would normally go in /usr/local or /opt and if you want the user to be able to call it by a different name, use a symbolic link in /usr/local. That way the shell's standard executable search mechanism will find it without jumping through hoops to source new aliases.

Comment: @steeldriver My script installs several bits of software for which root access was required. This is why it needs to be run as root. It also has to setup a couple of things for the user (such as this alias). Currently the script gets installed to ~/statusmonitor/ in the users home folder, because that it where I installed it originally before discovering that I was going to need root access.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance about UNIX stuff, but are you saying that if I want to have a script that is accessible from anywhere, it would be better to install it in /usr/local rather than in the user's home folder? Can I create a subfolder in usr/local and install it there? (there are actually two scripts that I need to create aliases for)